# Spring webflow - send link to a flow by email

Tags: spring-webflow

I'm new using Webflow and I don't know how to do that:  
I want to implement a recovery password flow, I'm taking the user's email, generate a random ticket and store it with hibernate. The problem is that I don't know how send an email to the user with a link to another flow which should check if the ticket is valid and then let the user change his password. Before using webflow I was sending the next URL: 
 (http://localhost:8080/changePassword?ticket=15teumv5huebt...)  
changePassword is a view in my project but I know this URL will be overriden. 
Can anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if your flow's id is `"changePassword"`, you should be able to send a link with `"http://localhost:8080/changePassword?ticket=15teumv5huebt..."`

you might want to automatically replace localhost by the server ip and do the same for the port number

also you might have to use your application's name `"http://localhost:8080/appName/changePassword?ticket=15teumv5huebt..."`

Comment: I was confused because when the flow is created the URL turns to http://localhost:8080/changePassword?execution=e1s1, but it seems I can access to the "ticket" parameter anyway.